# $f(z)=z^2$ bijective? using polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, functions

Consider $f(z)=z^2$, or using polar coordinates: $f(r,\phi)=(r^2\cos(2\phi),r^2\sin(2\phi))$.

How can I see or prove that $f$ is bijective on $\{z \in \mathbb C:Re(z)>0\}\to\mathbb C \setminus\{z \in \mathbb R:z\le0\}$?

Comment: I don't think there's any particular tricks here. De Moivre's theorem is the most geometric way to tackle it, but working with Cartesian coordinates shouldn't be too bad either. What part are you struggling with in particular? Can you show the function is one-to-one? Onto?

Comment: Hint: take an impeller half-open and make it an impeller completely open.

Comment: @TheoBendit Well, clearly $f(-z)=f(z)$ so for injectivity we can't have both negative and positive $z$. But I don't know if there has to be more argumentation. And I don't know how to show surjectivity

Comment: My hint would be to try and write $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Re(z)>0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{R}:z\leq 0\}$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ given that $z=re^{\theta\pi i}$.

Comment: @drhab I don't know that you mean by half open impeller?

Answer (score 6):

A word of caution: it's not good to start talking about "positive" and "negative" complex numbers. Complex numbers are not ordered, so it's not meaningful to say $a + ib \ge 0$ or $a + ib \le 0$.

If we assume $f(z) = f(w)$, then
$$z^2 = w^2 \implies z^2 - w^2 = 0 \implies (z - w)(z + w) = 0.$$
By the zero product property, we have $z = w$ or $z = -w$ which are two possible solutions. We need to eliminate the $z = -w$ solution. Fortunately this isn't hard! Since it is assumed that both $z$ and $w$ are in our domain, they both have strictly positive real parts, so their sum $z + w$ also has a strictly positive real part, and hence cannot be equal to $0$. Thus we must have $z = w$, as required.

The simplest way to do surjectivity is using polar coordinates and De Moivre's theorem. If $w$ lies in the codomain (i.e. the complex plane except the ray of negative real numbers), then it has a principle argument strictly between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. That is, we can write
$$w = r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$$
where $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \theta < \pi$. What complex number squares to give $w$? In polar coordinates, it must take the form
$$z = s(\cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha))$$
and satisfy:
$$s^2(\cos(2\alpha) + i\sin(2\alpha)) = r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)).$$
So, it seems that we should let
$$z = \sqrt{r}(\cos(\theta/2) + i\sin(\theta/2)).$$
Then $f(z) = z^2 = w$. We just have to verify that $z$ lies in the domain. Note that
$$-\pi < \theta < \pi \implies -\frac{\pi}{2} < \frac{\theta}{2} < \frac{\pi}{2} \implies \cos(\theta/2) > 0,$$
hence the real part of $z$ is positive, as required. Thus, for all $w$ in the codomain, we have a $z$ in the domain such that $f(z) = w$, i.e. $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I think you meant $\implies\cos{(\theta/2)}$ near the end.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(z)=z^2$ takes the complex number $z=\rho e^{i \phi}$ and associates it to $z^2=\rho^2 e^{2i \phi}$. Now let $w = R e^{i \theta}$ be a complex number such that $R \neq 0$ and $\theta \neq \pi$; we can assume assume for simplicity that $-\pi < \theta < \pi$. Now it is easy to see that there exists a unique complex number $z_w$ with $Re(z_w)>0$ such that $w=f(z_w)$: from $\rho^2 = R$ and $e^{2i \phi} = e^{i \theta}$ we get 
$$ \rho=\sqrt{R}, \;\; \phi=\frac{1}{2}\theta.$$ Moreover the bound $-\pi < \theta < \pi$ yields $-\frac{1}{2}\pi < \phi < \frac{1}{2}\pi$, which ensures $Re(z_w)>0$.